# How to show $\sum_{n=1}^{a+b} \frac{(-1)^n}{n}\binom{n}{n-a,n-b,a+b-n}=0$

Tags: number-theory, binomial-coefficients

I was trying to prove directly that, for $a,b$ positive integers:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{a+b} \frac{(-1)^n}{n}\binom{n}{n-a,n-b,a+b-n}=0$$

Alternatively:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{a+b}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\binom{n}{a}\binom{a}{n-b}=0$$

This comes from trying to prove the formal power series identity:

> If $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n}$ then $$f(x)+f(y)=f(x+y-xy)$$

which we know is true because $f(x)=-\log(1-x)$ in the complex numbers when $|x|<1$.

I would like to prove this directly, without referencing logarithm, and it reduces to the above identity.

(Note: $\binom{n}{i,j,k}=\binom{n}{i}\binom{n-i}{j}=\frac{n!}{i!j!k!}$ is the trinomial coefficient, defined when $i+j+k=n$)

Comment: This is consequence of Gauss' hypergeometric theorem http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssHypergeometricTheorem.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a combinatorial answer to my own question, six years later.

Letting $i=a+b-n,$ the second form becomes, up to sign:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{a+b-1}(-1)^i\frac1{a+b-i}\binom{a+b-i}{a}\binom{a}{a-i}=0$$

But $$\binom{a}{a-i}=\binom ai$$ and $$\frac{1}{a+b-i}\binom{a+b-i}{a}=\frac1{a}\binom{a+b-i-1}{a-1}=\frac1{a}\binom{a+b-1-i}{b-i}$$

Also, $\binom ai$ is zero if $i>a,$ so we want:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{a}(-1)^i\binom ai\binom{a+b-1-i}{b-i}=0\tag1$$

Now that looks like an inclusion-exclusion formula.

Indeed, if $A$ is the set of all subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,a+b-1\}$ of size $b,$ the expression in $(1)$ is the inclusion-exclusion count of all elements of $A$ which do not include $1,2,3,\dots,a,$ which is obviously $0.$

Indeed, we get a more general combinatorial result:

> If $m\leq n$ and $k\geq 0,$ then: $$\sum_{i=0}^m(-1)^i\binom{m}i\binom{n-i}{k-i}=\binom{n-m}{k}$$

This can be seen as an inclusion-exclusion count for the case when $M\subseteq N,$ with $|M|=m, |N|=n,$ and we are counting all subsets of $N$ of size $k$ which don't contain any element of $M,$ which is just the subsets of size $k$ of $N\setminus M.$

The case $m=a, n=a+b-1, k=b$ gives $(1)$ when $b>0.$

Answer (score 6):

It is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[z^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^k$ in a series. This way we can write e.g.
\begin{align*}
[z^k](1+z)^n=\binom{n}{k}
\end{align*}

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=1}^{a+b}&\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\binom{n}{a}\binom{a}{n-b}\\
> &=\frac{1}{a}\sum_{n=1}^{a+b}(-1)^n\binom{n-1}{a-1}\binom{a}{n-b}\tag{1}\\
> &=\frac{1}{a}\sum_{n=0}^{a+b-1}(-1)^{n+1}\binom{n}{a-1}\binom{a}{n+1-b}\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{a}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}[z^{a-1}](1+z)^n[u^{n+1-b}](1+u)^a\tag{3}\\
> &=-\frac{1}{a}[z^{a-1}]\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n(1+z)^n[u^n]u^{b-1}(1+u)^a\tag{4}\\
> &=-\frac{1}{a}[z^{a-1}](-(1+z))^{b-1}(1-(1+z))^a\tag{5}\\
> &=(-1)^{a+b}\frac{1}{a}[z^{a-1}](1+z)^{b-1}z^a\tag{6}\\
> &=0
> \end{align*}
>   *Comment:*

- In (1) we use the binomial identity
  \begin{align*}
  \binom{n}{a}=\frac{n}{a}\binom{n-1}{a-1}
  \end{align*}
- In (2) we shift the index $n$ by $1$.
- In (3) we apply the *coefficient of* operator twice. We also extend the limits of the series without changing anything since we are adding zeros only.
- In (4) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator.
- In (5) we use the substitution rule of the *coefficient of* operator with $u:= -(1+z)$
  \begin{align*}
  A(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n [u^n]A(u)
  \end{align*}
- In (6) we observe the coefficient of $z^{a-1}$ is zero.

Comment: Verified most of it: (+1), Nice to see the substitution rule deployed.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Thanks a lot, Marko! I appreciate your kind support!

Comment: I have now checked everything. It is somewhat unusual to use $n$ as the index but this is a matter of taste and indeed it was what the OP presented in the question.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Thanks Marko. Generally I try to stick at OPs notation, as long as there are no convincing reasons for a change.